# Display random Images in product category page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to show random images/video in product category pages. Every category page will display their own set of images.

I did it in the typical rookie way by adding in every product category page with their own respective set of images. Is there a way that I can use hooks to do it at functions.php for ease of maintenance?

```js
var total_images = 7;
var image1 = document.getElementById('banner1');
var image2 = document.getElementById('banner2');
var image3 = document.getElementById('banner3');
var random_numbers = [];
var random_number;
var random_img = [];

random_img[0] = '<a href="banner1.jpeg"><img src="banner1.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[1] = '<a href="banner2.jpeg"><img src="banner2.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[2] = '<a href="banner3.jpeg"><img src="banner3.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[3] = '<a href="banner4.jpeg"><img src="banner4.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[4] = '<a href="banner5.jpeg"><img src="banner5.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[5] = '<a href="banner6.jpeg"><img src="banner6.jpeg"></a>';
random_img[6] = '<a href="banner7.jpeg"><img src="banner7.jpeg"></a>';

while(random_numbers.length < 3){
  random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * total_images));
  if(random_numbers.indexOf(random_number) < 0){
    random_numbers.push(random_number);
  }
}

image1.innerHTML = random_img[random_numbers[0]];
image2.innerHTML = random_img[random_numbers[1]];
image3.innerHTML = random_img[random_numbers[2]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way - Install ACF plugin and create your fields - https://prnt.sc/1yek9zy .
For image field select image url. Duplucate Banner 1 as many banners you want and setup Location rules to taxonomy product category - https://prnt.sc/1yekgys

Then go to a product category and add your images and urls - https://prnt.sc/1yeklpf
If you have ACF pro go with repeater field instead. Its more dynamic and you can add as many banners you want per product category.

Use this visual hook guide to change where you want the banners to be showed - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/

```
function woo_category_banners() {
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $banners = get_field('banners', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
    if($banners):
    echo '<div class="banners">';
    foreach($banners as $k => $banner):
        $banner_data = $banners[$k];
        echo '<div class="banner"><a href="'.$banner_data['banner_url'].'"><img src="'.$banner_data['banner_image'].'"></a></div>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</div>';
    endif;
    
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop','woo_category_banners',40);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! Never thought of doing it this way! `woocommerce_before_shop_loop` is where I want it to be, however, the banner doesn't display on the page. I double checked that the field group Is created correctly and using theme twenty-twenty to check. I checked the browser inspector and is not there. I tried to add shortcode on the page following this guide https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/ but still to no avail.  I'm not familiar with ACF, is there a step that I need to incorporate to display the value? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry i did a typo mistake instead of banners i typed cat_banners. I have updated my code. If you still dont see the banner resave your category banners

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried but still doesn't display on the page. The images and url are saved correctly. I've disabled all plugins except woocommerce and ACF, and is using default twentytwenty to test. I tried to echo `some text` just in case it could be the images issues but still to no avail. The browser inspector doesn't show the css either. There is no error with WP_DEBUG.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. There is an error msg `Notice: Undefined property: WP_Post_Type::$taxonomy in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/functions.php`on line 793 which is the line that is edited from `cat_banners` to `banners`

Comment: I have tested with 2020 theme and its working - https://prnt.sc/1yj9evd

Comment: Thanks for the patience and help. These are the settings, not sure if I have missed any? https://ibb.co/SyrzJk2 https://ibb.co/5BqTR31 https://ibb.co/s9z90DQ https://ibb.co/1rRYG3f https://ibb.co/n16dx1r

Comment: Thanks! This works now. I have overlooked the setting for the image return format and hence the error message. After changing it to IMAGE URL, the images shown. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have developed something similar in the past, but not in javascript, it was all php code.
I had added a new banner field in the categories with ACF (only one, you would have many), and then on the category page I would show that banner or, recursively, the father's banner, until I found one.
You would have multiple image fields, and you would extract one at random, maybe it can be useful to you.

In any case, the hook to use is: woocommerce_before_main_content action.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content','bannertop');
function bannertop() {recursebanner('banner_top','bannertop');}
function recursebanner($type,$class) {
    if ( is_tax( 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $term = get_queried_object();
        $banner = get_field('banner_top', $term);
        if ($banner) {
            echo '<div class="'.$class.'">';
            echo $banner;
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            // no banner defined, parse ancestors
            $cat_ancestors = get_ancestors( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' );
            foreach ($cat_ancestors as $cat_ancestor) {
                $termancestor = get_term($cat_ancestor);
                $banner = get_field($type, $termancestor);
                if ($banner) {
                    echo '<div class="'.$class.'">';
                    echo $banner;
                    echo '</div>';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use javascript instead, you have to add it in your js file in the child theme, and call the script for example like this:

```
$ (function () {
   // your code
});
```

Comment: $term is an object when $banner = get_field('banner_top', $term);  needs obj id so should be $term->term_id . $cat_ancestor is an id so no point to get term object. Even if you do it $termancestor is an object so  $banner = get_field($type, $termancestor); $termancestor should be $termancestor->term_id ? .

Comment: @MartinMirchev this code was written 2 or 3 years ago, and is still up and running on one site. Maybe ACF has changed the syntax of the function in the meantime.
I haven't used it since, so I don't know. 
But the concept doesn't change if you have to pass the id instead of the object.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. I guess more likely due to my unfamiliarity of ACF as I couldn't get @MartinMirchev version to work too. I'll take some time to learn about ACF to have a better understanding of how it works first. Thank you for sharing your knowledge and experience.

Comment: After going through the ACF documentation, tested this and still works too! Thanks